# `git status` shows (between more) `git diff --cached --name-only` and `git diff --name-only`?

Tags: git

Am I right if I state that `git status` shows (if we disregard untracked files)

`git diff --cached --name-only` (with green color)

and

`git diff --name-only` (with red color)

Is that true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially, yes, assuming you're talking about the long form `git status` output (in the short form the same information is squeezed into just two letters at the front of each file).  Note also that the colors are configurable; green and red are simply the defaults.